# Android studio 2.1.3 - invalid android plugin

Tags: android, android-studio

I've updated Android Studio to 2.1.3 version.

This is my main build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder/raw/master/repository'
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1' //version required
}
```

And in gradle-wrapper.properties I've put:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

It still says that the Android Plugin is not recognized, like this:

```
Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
```

Any idea of how to fix it?